# Unable to instantiate a Class(es) from service reference i.e .wsdl file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, wsdl, webservices-client

Am trying to access a web service methods which are available in .wsdl file.
here I am creating a client successfully but when am trying to initiate it with the help of it's namespace there am unable to do that.
for adding a service reference am following the process as below
**right click on solution name ->Add service Reference->putting the Phyasycal location's address of .wsdl file in Address->click go Button after that my window look alike**
[image]

**after this am Clicking on Advance button there am Unchecking the Option *Reused Types in Referenced Assemblies* and then Clicking on Ok Button.**
after doing All this procedure am just trying to **Initiate the class/interface** which is available inside that service but am unable to get any.and also there is no change in **App.config** file(it's console application so here i have a app.config file instead of web.config)
has anuybody faced the same issue befor?can any one help?

Comment: Show me how you added your namespace to the class where you want to instantiate the service.

Comment: Please show the code you're trying to setup to instantiate the service

Comment: using ConsoleApplication11.ServiceReference1;
this way am including the namespce.and after that am directly typing the class name which is there in that .wsdl file.